# how to filter sensitive data from xml in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, activemerchant

I have a Rails application which uses the ActiveMerchant gem.

When the ActiveMerchant gem posts an ssl request (e.g. to process a credit card) it logs the body as debug https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/connection.rb line 66

This debug has sensitive information such as passwords, usernames, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/">
<env:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>usernamehere</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">passwordhere</wsse:Password>
....
```

How can these sensitive fields be filtered out of the logs?

Comment: Why don't you disable debug log in production?

Comment: debug is useful when something goes wrong, hence I'm really just hoping to filter out parameters like is done so for forms in Rails